# Visual Studio Code terminal freezes when asking to overwrite file for Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, visual-studio-code, ember-cli

VS Code just installed update 1.34.0

I have created a new project in Ember. When I attempt to create a new route `ember g route application`, I am asked if I want to overwrite **app\templates\application.hbs**. When I press Y and then Enter, the terminal freezes. I have to close it and open a new one. Unfortunately, the route is not created.

Is anyone else getting this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this also happening if you aren't trying to override the application template?

Comment: @Jelhan No. I deleted the Application template and re-ran the command and it worked fine; both the route and the template were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the Application template and re-running the command. Though, I should not have to do this.